# Start Django FastCGI automatically when OS X boots

Tags: django, macos, nginx, fastcgi

I have Django FastCGI/nginx working nicely on OS X.  I start my FastCGI process from the terminal like so:

```
python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8000 --settings=settings
```

in my nginx.conf file I have:

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
```

I have nginx starting automatically using launchd as detailed [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/OSX_launchd).

**My question is:** what is the correct approach to getting the FastCGI process to start automatically when the machine boots?

Thank you!

Comment: If you already have FastCGI/nginx set up to run via a file at `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/nginx.plist` and you say it's starting automatically, then what's the problem?  Sounds like it should be already starting up when the machine boots.

Comment: nginx starts, but the django-fastcgi part is a separate process. nginx communicates over a socket (or named pipe, etc) to the django webapp process (through fastcgi, as I understand it).

Comment: Can you not repeat the process you used to get nginx to start to have the django fastcgi service start too?  With FastCGI, it doesn't matter what *order* the services start, they will find each other once an actual request is recieved.

Comment: I guess that's the answer, it just seemed odd that there were no examples out there! (OS X used for a production webserver? hah)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using wsgi in this case, given that the wsgi process is fired by nginx vs it being a "stand-alone" process. A typical nginx and wsgi config:

myproject.wsgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import djangorecipe.wsgi

application = djangorecipe.wsgi.main('settings', logfile='/var/log/django/myproject.wsgi.log')
```

myproject.nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myproject.com;

    # static resources
    location ^~ /static/ {
        alias   /var/www/myproject/static/;
        expires 31d;
    }

    wsgi_var  REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
    wsgi_var  QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
    wsgi_var  CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
    wsgi_var  CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;
    wsgi_var  SERVER_NAME         $server_name;
    wsgi_var  SERVER_PORT         $server_port;
    wsgi_var  SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;

    # additional variables (not used if unavailable)
    wsgi_var  REQUEST_URI         $request_uri;
    wsgi_var  DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
    wsgi_var  DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
    wsgi_var  SERVER_SOFTWARE     $nginx_version;
    wsgi_var  REMOTE_ADDR         $remote_addr;
    wsgi_var  REMOTE_PORT         $remote_port;
    wsgi_var  SERVER_ADDR         $server_addr;
    wsgi_var  REMOTE_USER         $remote_user;

    location  / {
        client_body_buffer_size 50;
        wsgi_pass /var/www/myproject/myproject.wsgi;

        wsgi_pass_authorization off;
        wsgi_script_reloading on;
        wsgi_use_main_interpreter on;
    }

    # logging
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/myproject/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/myproject/error.log;
}
```

Comment: the `mod_wsgi` plugin for nginx has some serious downsides;  in particular, you lose the performance benefit of nginx as soon as a python application blocks, and django applications do that a lot (waiting for database/filesystem calls).

Comment: Thank you, I was completely unaware of that, although I have done a number of load tests on a similar setup.